# How to popup list like a spinner without spinner in android?

Tags: android, listview, popup, spinner

I have a spinner widget in my activity which lets users pick a list name.

Normally, the function of the spinner is to switch between lists but for a couple of instances, I swap out the selection change listener to perform a different function with the same list of options.  Once the selection has been made, the old listener is restored and life goes on.

This is a bad and buggy arrangement.  Instead, I would like to have a function that just takes a selection listener and some other parameters and shows a popup list that's populated by the same cursor (or and identical cursor) as the spinner, without using the spinner itself.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `AlertDialog.Builder` and supply an `Adapter` via `setAdapter()` that generates your rows.

In your case, I would not use the same `Cursor`, as a `Cursor` has an intrinsic notion of the current row, and so messing with the `Cursor` while it is used by your `SpinnerAdapter` could screw up the `Spinner`. Go with an identical `Cursor`.

Comment: I had no idea an AlertDialog.Builder had that functionality.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll accept your answer if I get it to work out.

Answer (score 11):

This is best example for popup details like spinner using AlertDialog and AlertDialog.Builder

```
        AlertDialog dialog;

         final CharSequence[] items = { "Item1", "Item2" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                              {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked on:"+items[pos],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      }break;
            case 1:
                              {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked on:"+items[pos],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      }break;
        }
    }});
dialog=builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: awesome!  Just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not limited by API level 11 then  [listPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) is close to what you want.

Comment: this should be more popular among the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
            CharSequence[] items = {"Mangoes", "Bananas", "Grapes"};

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Action")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if(item==0){
                      // Mangoes selected
                    }
                    else if(item==1){
                      // Bananas selected
                    }
                    else if(item==2){
                      // Grapes selected
                    }   
                }

            })
            .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

see [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/working-with-androids-popupmenu-class/#) example