# Spinner OnItemSelected doesn't work

Tags: android, events, click, spinner

I've reviewed my code several times and tried different "solutions", obviously none of them worked. The problem is that listener never get's fired when an item is clicked. I found out that  when an item is clicked this appears in Logcat:

> Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40683498

The Spinner is created dynamically in a function fired by Button.

> Code :

```
public void showFilterCountries(View v){

     Spinner country_list=new Spinner(this);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     country_list.setAdapter(adapter);
     country_list.setPrompt("Select a country");

     country_list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                Log.d("","selected");                   
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                Log.d("","none selected");
            }
        });

     country_list.performClick();
    }
```

Comment: where yu added country_list on UI ?

Comment: I never show my Spinner on UI. I just need the "selection list" which I show using country_list.performClick().

Comment: I would try removing the anonymous inner class (where your listener is set) and instead have your class implement OnItemSelectedListener.  Then put your item selected logic in the overridden method.  Just a guess.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you don't show the spinner in the UI, will it get events?

Comment: Maybe that was the problem yes. This is a wrong way to use Spinner. I solved the issue and posted an answer :)

Comment: @cstrutton same thing I am saying utill you add the spinner you will not get the  events.... any how you get the event to open Spinner (performClick()) but item selection is no where........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using AlertDialog.Builder instead of Spinner (which is the right way), like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7635966/1181261

Comment: this is not answer to question

Comment: I think this is the right answer because this is the proper way one should implement such a popup list - and not with Spinner.

Comment: I asked this question and before I was doing it the wrong way. Spinner isn't meant for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this, one spinner I had wouldn't work.  The issue is that it is in a fragment that implemented AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, the problem being that it was in activity that also implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, the issue is that the activity always catches the event, so I had to put my logic in the fragment, and have the activity call the fragment method.

TL:DR, if your onItemSelected is never called, it may be activity, or another listener catching it, apparently Android only likes one thing listening for onItemSelected.